# Ошибка при работе регулярных выражениями

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-2.x

[image: скрин кода и ошибки компилятора]

мне нужно из item вытянуть все значения от http:// до / .

```
 import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link = raw_input("Enter keyword: ")
response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select('.r a'):
    mylist =[]
    mylist = re.findall(r'https:\/\/(.*)\/',item.text)
    print(mylist)
```

вывод

```
   Enter keyword: ss
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

По идее код должен выводить выводить ссылки

Я полагаю проблема в

```
mylist =[]
        mylist = re.findall(r'https:\/\/(.*)\/',item.text)
        print(mylist)
```

ибо до этого фрагмента кода всё выполняет свою функцию. без фрагмента, выше скрипт в результате выдаёт текст такого вида

> https://www.shopandship.com/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwigq-TU17XgAhXQE7kGHTzeD94QFgg8MAU&usg=AOvVaw1bOyczw9dwevaHcV0H9A0_">**Shop** & Ship

Comment: Добавьте код текстом.

Comment: Какую ошибку?..

Comment: Смотри терминал , там предпоследняя строка unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Текст ошибки - в тело вопроса. Картинки тут не смотрят.

Comment: Убери экранирование в регулярном выражении. Если префикс r, то экранировать не нужно.

Comment: @daydreamer во-первых, исключение `IndentationError` означает, что в коде неправильно расставлены отступы. Во-вторых, я скопировал код из вопроса и нормально запустил у себя.

Comment: Обновил пост ,  с отступами разобрался , но увы код возвращает пустоту ...

Comment: В тексте не встречается последовательность "https:\/\/", потому и пустоту.

Comment: Возможно, `re.findall(r'https?://([^/]+)',item.text)` сработает, конечно, только при наличии ссылок в тексте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярки не нужны

```
import re
import sys
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


kw = raw_input('Enter keyword: ')
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', params={'q': + kw})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select('.r a'):
    qs = parse_qs(urlparse(item.get('href', '')).query)
    if 'q' in qs:
        print(qs['q'][0])
```